# Big SQLITE database in iOS

Tags: ios, database, ipad, sqlite

In my ios app I have got an sqlite database with more then 800.000 rows. More or less only text in the rows. At the moment my select statement needs more than a minute to perform. Is that normal or do I something wrong.

**Is there any possibility to speed that task up?**

My problem is, that I **cant** do it with a webservice or something else. It should be performed right on the iPad without any connection to the internet.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's difficult to offer advice in the abstract, but in general:

1. Measure. Find *where* and *why* there are bottle necks
2. Improve code / database scheme
3. Go to 1

The best tool for (1) is the "[explain plan](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)" feature of SQLite. This tells you *how* it's going to get your results. If it's taking over a minute I think you'll see lots of full table scans.

The answer for (2) depends on what you find on (1). You might be able to improve the query; you might need index(es).

Point (3) is important. Don't guess at what makes the best performance improvemets. Measure.

Comment: thanks for your hints. I see that my problem is, that I have not enough knowledge about databases :) I was confused because on my sqlite manager the query needs 150ms and I thought it should not be so much more with sqlite on my ipad(?).

Comment: Sorry. I think now might be a good time to learn about databases. Remember that you Mac is substantially faster than your iPad. If nothing else, it can probably hold the entire database in memory.

Comment: Of course its faster. But from 150ms to 120seconds?:o) I thought the difference can't be like that. But thanks for your help - Im going to improve my database knowledge :)

Comment: I read the explain plan you had linked in your answer and now added a important index on my sqlite table. My sql needs now only 36ms instead of 120seconds. I think your answer might be a good help for somebody like me who hasn't got much database knowhow - so I accepted it.

Comment: I have a requirement for a very similar app: queries with many criteria combinations on a 1,000,000+ SQLite database. I'm glad to hear that it's possible to have fast responses in a 800,000 row database.